# How to have multiple http configurations with akka-http

Tags: scala, http, akka, connection-pooling, akka-http

With akka-http, you can provide typesafe config as described [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/configuration.html) which is put in `application.conf`. so a minified config can look like following:

```
akka.http {
  client {
    connecting-timeout = 10s
  }
  host-connection-pool {
    max-connections = 4
    max-open-requests = 32
  }
}
```

My question is if I have to call different external services in the app, I create different pool to those. How do I change these config(max-connections, max-open-requests) for these different pools calling different external services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I have found so far for this is, overwriting the [connectionPoolSettings](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.6/akka/http/scaladsl/settings/ConnectionPoolSettings.html) and passing it when creating http pool:

```
Http().superPool[RequestTracker](
      settings = ConnectionPoolSettings(httpActorSystem).withMaxOpenRequests(1).withMaxConnections(1)
    )(httpMat)
```

Here I can provide appropriate config for `maxOpenRequests` and `maxConnections`as par my requirement.